# Information on network interface from udp broadcast

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have code that looks something like

```
IPEndPoint ipendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(25001, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
byte[] recv = client.Receive(ref ipendpoint);
```

I'm sending a broadcast with pc1 and pc2 with this code is in the same network thus receiving a message that pc1 has send. pc2 listens on every networkinterface(because of IPAdress.Any) which is a good thing, because pc2 can have more than 1 networkinterface. Now i would like to know on which networkinterface/IP this message actually came in. Is there a possibility to retrieve this information?

I already tried debugging but none of the objects seemed to have the information i need.

Answer (score 0):

After the client sends the data you can look at:

```
 ipendpoint.Address
 ipendpoint.Port
```

To get the ip and port.

Comment: no sorry, but that gives me information about the source of the message(pc1). I want to know where it came in on pc2.